# How to run iOS app on device without attaching device to Mac?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, applications, xcode

My client has an iPhone and iPad at his place and wants to check the app being created by us at our place.

We are able to check the iOS app on our registered iPhone by attaching it to our Mac and running Xcode with the proper certificate.

The client has provided the details for their device (the UDID and other details). Now my issue is that how can the client run the app on their devices?

Answer (score 1):

My team uses [Test Flight](http://testflightapp.com/) for managing and deploying beta iOS applications. It's easy for both the developer and the tester to use, as it does all the provisioning and distribution for you. It also happens to be [free to use](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/821658-is-it-really-free-).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add their UUID to your devices list on the developer web site, and then create an 'Ad-hoc' provisioning profile that contains your App ID and their Device ID (any any other device IDs you want). Now build and archive your app from Xcode, and choose 'Ad-Hoc' - if the option isn't available make sure you have a phone connected.

You'll end up with a .IPA file that can be emailed and dragged into iTunes for install.

This creates an app that is as about as similar to a Live app as you can get, so for example Push Notification will need to use the Live Certificate. If you're sending to a client, I would recommend you add one of your phones into the provisioning profile and try the iTunes install on a clean machine and on a phone with no development profiles installed, just to be sure it works.

As mentioned above, you can also use a 3rd party service to do this, but you don't need to and I never have, though it may well be easier.

See 
https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html

and

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html for full instructions.